# Efficient algorithm to convert integer to decimal

Tags: algorithm

Problem 31.1-12 of the CLRS algorithms book asks the following question:

> Give an efficient algorithm to convert a given `β`-bit (binary) integer to a decimal representation. Argue that if multiplication or division of integers whose length is at most `β` takes time `M(β)`, then binary-to-decimal conversion can be performed in time `Θ( M(β) lg β)`. (*Hint:* Use a divide-and-conquer approach, obtaining the top and bottom halves of the result with separate recursions.

It asks for time `Θ( M(β) lg β)`. How is that even possible for a divide and conquer algorithm given that `lg β` alone is the height of the recursion tree? Does anyone know what the intended solution is?

Answer (score 0):

For the hint to work, it must be the case that M(β) is a linear function; in particular, that M(β) ≈ 2·M(β/2).

If that is given, there is an obvious solution:  Recursively split the data into parts, process the parts separately, and combine the results.  At level k of the recursion there will be 2ᵏ parts, each of length approximately  β/(2ᵏ) bits, or about β total.  The processing at level k costs 2ᵏ·M(β/(2ᵏ)) ≈ M(β), whence O(M(β)·lg β) total time.

To split a value u with β bits and process its two parts (v,w), let 2·d or 2·d+1 = ⌊β·ln(2)/ln(10)⌋; let v = ⌊u/10ᵈ⌋ and w = u-v·10ᵈ.

Comment: I think the book was actually suggesting to treat M as a constant, so that we need to make the conversion with lg B multiplications. This answer still makes 2^k ~ O(B) multiplications, so probably isn't what the book is looking for. Additions are assumed to be much cheaper such that the cost of multiplications dominate them.