# Converting a BigInteger to a string in some base: speed issue (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, base-conversion

I want to convert large positive `BigInteger`s (up to many thousands of digits) to strings in Kotlin, using number bases up to 100 (and possibly higher).

For bases ≤36, there is of course `toString(base)`, but for larger bases, I wrote this extension function:

```
fun BigInteger.toStringX(base: Int): String {
    if (base <= 36) return toString(base)  // improve speed if base <= 36
    val bigBase = base.toBigInteger()
    var n = this
    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
    while (n > ZERO) {
        val div = n.divideAndRemainder(bigBase)
        stringBuilder.append(DIGITS[div[1].toInt()])
        n = div[0]
    }
    return stringBuilder.reverse().toString()
}
```

where `DIGITS` is a string containing the list of digits.

Now the native `toString` is faster by about an order of magnitude than my function – e.g. 60 ms for about 10,000 digits vs. 500 ms. Why is my function so slow? Any help improving on its speed (while maintinaing the ability to convert to bases > 36) would be appreciated.

(By the way, replacing `append()` with `insert()` and losing `reverse()` in the last line doesn't change much.)

Comment: The builtin `toString` seems to use a [`O(log(n))` algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47949495/5133585) where `n` is the number of bits in the number. It's the recursive Schoenhage algorithm for base conversions. See also: the ACP Vol. 2 by Donald Knuth, Answers to Exercises (4.4) Question 14.

Comment: @Sweeper: Thanks for the link; I'll try to implement this algorithm and see what it does to my computing time.

Comment: [This might help](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L4062)

Comment: Cool! I'd accept this as an answer but I don't think that's possible for a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the built-in `toString`, it seems to call [this private `toString`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java#L4062), which implements a divide-and-conquer algorithm.

```
/**
 * Converts the specified BigInteger to a string and appends to
 * {@code sb}.  This implements the recursive Schoenhage algorithm
 * for base conversions. This method can only be called for non-negative
 * numbers.
 * <p>
 * See Knuth, Donald,  _The Art of Computer Programming_, Vol. 2,
 * Answers to Exercises (4.4) Question 14.
 *
 * @param u      The number to convert to a string.
 * @param sb     The StringBuilder that will be appended to in place.
 * @param radix  The base to convert to.
 * @param digits The minimum number of digits to pad to.
 */
private static void toString(BigInteger u, StringBuilder sb,
                             int radix, int digits) {

    ...

    results = u.divideAndRemainder(v);

    int expectedDigits = 1 << n;

    // Now recursively build the two halves of each number.
    toString(results[0], sb, radix, digits - expectedDigits);
    toString(results[1], sb, radix, expectedDigits);

}
```

This means that there is only O(log(N)) divisions, for an N-bit number. Compare this to your algorithm, which does O(N) divisions.

So for large numbers, you can implement this algorithm too - "split" the number up into smaller ones, then use your O(N) algorithm when they are small enough, all the while passing the string builder along, so the digits are appended.